# innerHTML removes attribute quotes in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xhtml, innerhtml

When you get the innerHTML of a DOM node in IE, if there are no spaces in an attribute value, IE will remove the quotes around it, as demonstrated below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1"><div id="div2"></div></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert(document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In IE, the alert will read:

```
<DIV id=div2></DIV>
```

This is a problem, because I am passing this on to a processor that requires valid XHTML, and all attribute values must be quoted.  Does anyone know of an easy way to work around this behavior in IE?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IE innerHTML is very annoying indeed. I wrote this function for it, which may be helpfull? It quotes attributes and sets tagnames to lowercase. By the way, to make it even more annoying, IE's innerHTML doesn't remove quotes from non standard attributes.

**Edit based on comments**
The function now processes more characters in attribute values and optionally converts attribute values to lower case. The function looks even more ugly now ;~). If you want to add or remove characters to the equation, edit the `[a-zA-Z\.\:\[\]_\(\)\&\$\%#\@\!0-9]+[?\s+|?>]` part of the regular expressions.

```
function ieInnerHTML(obj, convertToLowerCase) {
    var zz = obj.innerHTML ? String(obj.innerHTML) : obj
       ,z  = zz.match(/(<.+[^>])/g);    

    if (z) {
     for ( var i=0;i<z.length;(i=i+1) ){
      var y
         ,zSaved = z[i]
         ,attrRE = /\=[a-zA-Z\.\:\[\]_\(\)\&\$\%#\@\!0-9\/]+[?\s+|?>]/g
      ;

      z[i] = z[i]
              .replace(/([<|<\/].+?\w+).+[^>]/,
                 function(a){return a.toLowerCase();
               });
      y = z[i].match(attrRE);

      if (y){
        var j   = 0
           ,len = y.length
        while(j<len){
          var replaceRE = 
               /(\=)([a-zA-Z\.\:\[\]_\(\)\&\$\%#\@\!0-9\/]+)?([\s+|?>])/g
             ,replacer  = function(){
                  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                  return '="'+(convertToLowerCase 
                          ? args[2].toLowerCase() 
                          : args[2])+'"'+args[3];
                };
          z[i] = z[i].replace(y[j],y[j].replace(replaceRE,replacer));
          j+=1;
        }
       }
       zz = zz.replace(zSaved,z[i]);
     }
   }
  return zz;
}
```

Example key-value pairs that should work

```
data-mydata=return[somevalue] => data-mydata="return[somevalue]"
id=DEBUGGED:true => id="DEBUGGED:true" (or id="debugged:true" if you use the convertToLowerCase parameter)
someAttribute=Any.Thing.Goes => someAttribute="Any.Thing.Goes"
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I'm going to select it as the accepted answer anyway, because it comes closest to being a self-contained solution to the question.

Comment: Ok, thanx. In my tests it worked, but didn't test it thourougly. Out of curiosity: who think this answer deserves a -1 score and why?

Comment: I remember when I had to work with a huge legacy application that all logic was using innerHTML. I remember the problem it had since in one of the examples, using innerHTML in a tbody tag is readonly (as some other elements).

Comment: +1 Nicely done. What would be *even nicer* is lowercasing style attributes as well, such as `style="DISPLAY: none"`.

Comment: @mofle and @Creshent Fresh: see the modifications I posted

Comment: By the way, although anything goes (see examples), as far as I know not all characters are allowed as attribute values for all attributes, so if its valid xhtml you're after, you should be carefull using these values.

Comment: Thanks! :) Can you add support for hyphens in the attribute value to?
I have a testcase here: http://wroug.com/bugs/ieinnerhtml/test.html
Also, it would be useful, if the attribute name is "style", then lowercase the whole value, if converttolowercase is true.

Comment: @mofle: try modifying the regex (add \- between []). As far as the style attribute is concerned: that's beyond te goal of this function. The goal is to convert de unquoted attribute values IE returns from innerHTML to quoted attribute values. Style is untouched by IE's innerHTML, sorry.

Comment: I assume you mean like this
zz.match(/<\/?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[\-^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>/g); but it doesn't work. Any help? :) About the style, no worries, but it's strange, I have my style values in lowercase, but IE output them in uppercase, anyway, that's an easy fix I can do myself.

Comment: Nope, I mean [a-zA-Z\.\:\[\]_\(\)\&\$\%#\@\!0-9] (twice in the function), replace with [a-zA-Z\-\.\:\[\]_\(\)\&\$\%#\@\!0-9]

Comment: Aah, right. Thanks :D Sorry for the bother. Maybe you should update the function with this. Could be useful for other people too.

Comment: @KooiInc can you show some demo, JSFiddle, as i am having tough time with innerHTml:( it will help me to understad. how to use this function .please help us :(

Comment: @KooiInc please help me to understand this function, i really struck with my project :( please i'll offer you some bounty :( please yaar

Comment: You could modify your function by redefining .innerHTML, as well. For example, http://jsfiddle.net/DLLbc/9 or http://jsfiddle.net/DLLbc/12.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, the joy of trying to use XHTML in a browser that doesn't support it.

I'd just accept that you are going to get HTML back from the browser and put something in front of your XML processor that can input tag soup and output XHTML — [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) for example.

Comment: This is actually the solution I ended up going with. I opted to use the lxml Python library.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this exact same problem just over a year ago, and solved it using [InnerXHTML](http://www.stevetucker.co.uk/innerxhtml.htm), a custom script written by someone far smarter than I am. It's basically a custom version of innerHTML that returns standard markup.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at this library, but I would rather not use it because it is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0  License.

Comment: Fair enough. My employer at the time I used it was fine with it, but I understand that's not always the case.

Comment: Heh, I appreciate the vote of confidence, but the OP has already stated that the licensing terms for the library don't meet his needs.

Answer (score 3):

I might be couple year too late but here goes. Accepted answer might do what it promises but it's already Friday afternoon and I need something simpler nor I have time go it through. So here's my version which will just quote attribute values w/o quotes and it should be pretty trivial to extend it.

```
var t = "<svg id=foobar height=\"200\" width=\"746\"><g class=rules>";
t.replace(/([\w-]+)=([\w-]+)([ >])/g, function(str, $n, $v, $e, offset, s) {
    return $n + '="' + $v + '"' + $e;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tested this, and it works for most attributes, except those that are hyphenated, such as class=day-month-title. It ignores those attributes, and does not quote them.

Comment: Also, I had to change the regex, to: 

/<\/?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^\'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>/g

before it would work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick and dirty workaround for this issue. I used it when working with jQuery templates. Just add a trailing space to the value of the attribute.
Of course this does not make much sense with id that is used in the example, so here is another example involving jQuery, and jQuery templates:

http://jsfiddle.net/amamaenko/dW7Wh/5/

Note the trailing space in the line `<input value="${x} "/>` without it, the example won't work on IE.

Answer (score -6):

did you tried with jquery  ?

```
alert($('#div1').html());
```

Comment: Yup. jQuery uses innerHTML to return its value, and they haven't fixed this problem yet. I took jQuery out just to make it more clear where the problem lies.