# Javascript InnerHTML in IE7 messing with INPUT tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

When I receive the innerHTML of an element containing an input[type=text] element the speech marks around the value and id are removed in IE7 i.e.

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="test" />
```

Becomes:

```
<input type="text" id=test value=test />
```

This would be fine, other than the fact that I am using a JQuery plugin that takes a html segment and binds JSON to it. This means if I have a template:

```
<div id="template"><input type="text"  value="${ValueToBind}" /></div>
```

When I retrieve this via **document.getElementByID("template").innerHTML** i get:

```
<input type="text"  value=${ValueToBind} />
```

Thus, if I am binding a string with whitespace i.e. "this is a test" the output is:

```
<input type="text"  value=this is a test />
```

Obviously, this is invalid html and causing havoc with my app. What I really need to do it to retrieve the html in the template AS IS, and not have IE try to do anything helpful like remove the " speech marks.

Cheers, Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is IE7 specific a quick fix may be to add an [IE conditional comment](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/cc2.shtml) for IE7 with code that re-inserts the quote marks.

Comment: Your right, I tried searching. Just not hard enough by the look of things.

Answer (score 2):

answered here [innerHTML removes attribute quotes in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231770/innerhtml-removes-attribute-quotes-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this isn't something you can get around directly as the quotemark-less html is just how IE7 represents the DOM node internally.

My view on the best way to ensure you get the *exactly* right template is to read each attribute of each node yourself rather than the inner html and then write them out with the quote marks.

See

[innerHTML removes attribute quotes in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231770/innerhtml-removes-attribute-quotes-in-internet-explorer)

for other ideas.

Using jQuery's .html()

http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html

would generally be the "jQuery way" to do this also rather than .getElementById