# Send XML to flash with javascript, parse error only in IE

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm passing a piece of HTML from my page to a flash movie, where i want to parse it as XML.

i use jQuery to get the data from the page;

```
var htmlForFlash = escape($("#prodlinksWrap").html());
```

the HMTL i'm passing looks somewhat like this:

```
   <div id="prodlinks" class="noscript">
    <a href="/products/Quadrant.aspx">Quadrant</a> 
    <a href="/products/CampFire.aspx">CampFire</a>
   </div>
```

This works fine in FireFox, Chrome and Safari, but IE throws an error:

```
TypeError: Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed.
```

on this line:

```
var myXML : XML = new XML(data);
```

The error goes away when I delete all attributes in my xml, but offcourse that's not what i want. I already tried changing the quotes, adding a `<?xml ..>` tag, but no result so far.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using js/jQuery? You can import xml data directly in Flash, too.

Comment: The flash I use is a fallback for old browsers, the xml is already in my document. I don't want to make an extra call to the server to get this XML again. also that would mean i have to keep 2 versions of this XML on my server that i have to maintain.
If you want to see this at work: www.invotisorange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, 
When you get the innerHTML of a DOM node in IE, if there are no spaces or slashes in an attribute value, IE will remove the quotes around it.

Thanks Augustus and Coolnic !
For the solution see this question:

[innerHTML removes attribute quotes in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231770/innerhtml-removes-attribute-quotes-in-internet-explorer)